# Convert a date from DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD format in bash LINUX

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, date

Scenario:

I am fetching a date value from a file into a variable and it is in DD-MM-YYYY format by default. I have to substract this date from system date. Subtraction is giving incorrect result if I had both dates in DD-MM-YYYY format. So I read a bit on google and decided to format both dates as YYYY-MM-DD as this will give correct value after subtraction. I have System date formatted successfully in YYYY-MM-DD, but facing a hard time to convert the date obtained from the file to YYYY-MM-DD format.

Below solution works fine with single digit dates:

```
$ date -d $(sed "s/-/\//g" <<< '9-2-1832') +%Y-%m-%d
Output : 1832-09-02
```

but when I try to convert date in double digits like below:

```
$ date -d $(sed "s/-/\//g" <<< '19-07-2021') +%Y-%m-%d
```

I get output

```
Invalid date '19/07/2021'
```

Where:

```
19 - is Date of a month
07 - is Month i.e. July in this case.
2021 - is Year
```

Desired output as -> `2021-07-19`

I am working on RH Linux with Date version as: date (GNU coreutils) 8.22

Please help to provide a solution for above problem.

Comment: The first one didn't *work fine* as it gave you 1832-09-02 instead of 1832-02-09 for 9-2-1832. IOW, your `date` interpreted the date as if it was in US format (m-d-y) instead of d-m-y).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can reproduce this on my Arch, and using `LC_ALL=el_GR.utf8`  or `LC_ALL=es_ES.utf8` or `LC_ALL=fr_FR.utf8` doesn't make a difference, although all of those use DD-MM-YYYY and print the right format with `+%x`. This is a bug in GNU `date`, right?

Comment: @terdon, no, it works as documented, GNU date expects date is a limited number of formats, generally US style, and that's independant of the locale. See `info date cal`

Comment: I find GNU `date` weird: it jumps through hoops to try to accept all sorts of "intuitive" date inputs, but doesn't let you *tell* it what the format is when it's impossible to guess. (BSD `date` is much nicer in this respect.) Granged, `19` can't be a month, but GNU `date` doesn't seem to go so far as to assume it must be a day and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @chepner, about that, see [that discussion on the coreutils mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2019-07/msg00053.html) and continued [there](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2019-08/msg00002.html)

Comment: Do you have no control over the file?  If you could arrange for that to be in YYYY-MM-DD format too, then your life would be much easier :-)  (I don't understand why everyone isn't using [ISO-format dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) everywhere by now…)

Comment: how do you subtract dates?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen that should be asked as a new question, shouldn't it? ;)

Comment: @adminbee no that is a leading question…

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your case, `awk` might be a better method:

```
$ awk -F'-' '{printf("%04d-%02d-%02d\n",$3,$2,$1)}' <<< '19-07-2021'
2021-07-19
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephane. I have posted my answer which helped solving my problem, but I think yours would work too as the approach looks similar.

Comment: Awk is able to do it directly:`awk -F'-' '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d",mktime($3" "$2" "$1" 0 0 0"))}' <<< '19-07-2021'`

Comment: @ImHere True, but it _is_ somewhat longer the simple `printf` approach, don't you think? ;)

Comment: The simple printf doesn't *validate* the date.

Answer (score 13):

You could switch to busybox `date` which allows specifying the input  format:

```
$ date=19-7-2021
$ busybox date -D %d-%m-%Y -d "$date" +%F
2021-07-19
```

(beware it won't accept `019-007-2021` dates for instance).

Same with the ast-open implementation of `date` (unlikely to be available out of the box on your RedHat system):

```
$ date -p %d-%m-%Y -d "$date" +%F
2021-07-19
```

If you were on BSD instead of a GNU system, you'd do:

```
$ date -jf %d-%m-%Y -- "$date" +%F
2021-07-19
```

Or you could switch to `zsh` instead of `bash` as is has a date parsing and formatting builtin:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ strftime -rs t %d-%m-%Y $date && strftime %F $t
2021-07-19
```

(`strftime` being the builtin that gives access to the standard `strftime()` and `strptime()` (with `-r`) APIs).

It also has proper splitting operators and a `printf` that can take arguments in arbitrary orders (using the `%n$...` syntax as found in most `printf()` implementations including GNU `printf()`, but not the `printf` builtin of `bash` nor the GNU `printf` standalone utility), and it doesn't treat numbers with leading zeros as octal by default:

```
$ printf '%3$04d-%2$02d-%1$01d\n' ${(s[-])date}
2021-07-19
```

Or using an anonymous function:

```
$ (){ printf '%04d-%02d-%02d\n' $3 $2 $1; } ${(s[-])date}
2021-07-19
```

Or here, the array reversing operator:

```
$ printf '%04d-%02d-%02d\n' ${(s[-]Oa)date}
2021-07-19
```

Answer (score 8):

If the format is hardcoded as `DD-YY-YYYY`, you can also hardcode the whole expression and use [substring extraction](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to reformat, which is very fast:

```
#!/bin/bash
dmy=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
ymd="${dmy: -4}-${dmy:3:2}-${dmy:0:2}"
echo "$dmy -> $ymd"
```

If the format is `D[D]-M[M]-YYYY` you could use [regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) to reformat, which is somewhat slower:

```
#!/bin/bash
dmy="9-2-1932"
if [[ "$dmy" =~ ^([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+)$ ]] ; then
  ymd="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
echo "$dmy -> $ymd"
```

You can format that a bit nicer with [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins):

```
dmy="9-02-2032"
if [[ "$dmy" =~ ^([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+)$ ]] ; then
  printf -v ymd '%.4d-%.2d-%.2d' \
    "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
echo "$dmy -> $ymd"
```

---

A former version of this answer is evidence that I didn't read it fully, converting `YYYY-MM-DD` to `DD-MM-YYYY`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ymd=$(date  +%Y-%m-%d)
dmy="${ymd: -2}-${ymd:5:2}-${ymd:0:4}"
echo "$ymd -> $dmy"
```

Comment: `${ymd: -2}${ymd:4:4}${ymd:0:4}`

Comment: Note that one of their examples is the date string `9-2-1832`.

Comment: @Kusalananda That was a it hidden, but I can't read anyway. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks all you guys for pitching in with various solutions. I believe few of the suggested solutions would work out for me as I correlate them to the approach I used in solving it on my own yesterday, right after posting this question.

I used `IFS` to achieve it.

```bsh
IFS=- read d m y <<<'19-7-2021'
printf '%.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n' "${y#0}" "${m#0}" "${d#0}"
```

This would output `2021-07-19`.

The `${m#0}` etc. removes an initial `0` from the value of `$m`, in case the original month happens to be `08` or `09` which would otherwise be interpreted as invalid octal numbers.

Comment: Just FYI you can force bash computations to be in base 10 by using `$((10#$m))`. It usually helps also because it will *not* replace single-digit 0 with nothing (as does `${m#0}`). Also, even empty variables become 0. But neither can happen in your case, so this suggestion only make the whole slightly more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and lean solution that uses only sed:

```bsh
echo 19-07-2021 | sed -E 's/^([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{4})$/\3-\2-\1/'
```

Comment: They also have an example saying `9-2-1832`...

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -lne 'print reverse split /(-)/, s/\b\d\b/0$&/rg' <<<"19-7-2021"
2021-07-19
```

Split on dash `/(-)/` , with the dashes included in the split up array but before that change the date to double digits in day and/or month.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in many .txt files and wrote a simple one line:

```
sed -i -E 's/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\3-\2-\1/g' ./*.txt
```

Comment: This won't catch all the cases. See Kusalananda's comment on my answer.

Comment: @DanielWerner so the dates are written badly, can't do much about it. Seems like your solution is the right one here. My is more general for proper data.

Answer (score 0):

an universal approach using python: (standalone with User Input)

```
python3 -c 'import datetime as dt; format="%d-%m-%Y"; print(dt.datetime.strptime(input(f"input time in format {format}: "), format).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")); '
input time in format %d-%m-%Y: 9-2-1832
1832-02-09
```

for pipable just remove input query (single value conversion):

```
echo "9-2-1832"| python3 -c 'import datetime as dt; print(dt.datetime.strptime(input(), "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")); '
1832-02-09
```

and finally pipable, to convert list of string-dates:

```
echo -e "9-2-1832\n1-2-1234\n31-12-2020"| python3 -c 'import sys,datetime;[sys.stdout.write(datetime.datetime.strptime(line.strip(), "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+"\n") for line in sys.stdin]'
1832-02-09
1234-02-01
2020-12-31
```

the power of this unbeautiful solution is that ANY possible formats can be used for input or output, explicitly seen and easily updated if needed, unlike hardcoded regular expressions...
for instance, one can convert dates to ISO YEAR-WEEK:

```
echo -e "9-2-1832\n1-2-1234\n31-12-2020"| python3 -c 'import sys,datetime;[sys.stdout.write(datetime.datetime.strptime(line.strip(), "%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%G-%V")+"\n") for line in sys.stdin]'
1832-06
1234-05
2020-53
```

for more format specifiers see `date --help`

Answer (score 0):

A little late to pitch in, but worth mentioning this awk method too:

```
$ echo "2021-07-19" | awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-" }{print $3,$2,$1}'
19-07-2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*To start, here's a `raku` translation of @AdminBee's excellent `awk` answer:*

```bash
~$ raku -e 'printf("%04d-%02d-%02d\n", .[2,1,0]) given $*IN.split("-");' <<< '19-07-2021'
2021-07-19
```

Raku has built-in Date routines like `yyyy-mm-dd`, `dd-mm-yyyy`, and `mm-dd-yyyy`. So above can more easily be written as follows (add `chomp` to get rid of the newline added to here-string):

```
~$ raku -e 'Date.new( .[2,1,0].join("-")).put given $*IN.split("-")>>.chomp;'  <<< '19-07-2021'
2021-07-19
~$ raku -e 'Date.new( .[2,1,0].join("-")).yyyy-mm-dd.put given $*IN.split("-")>>.chomp;'  <<< '19-07-2021'
2021-07-19
~$ raku -e 'Date.new( .[2,1,0].join("-")).dd-mm-yyyy.put given $*IN.split("-")>>.chomp;'  <<< '19-07-2021'
19-07-2021
~$ raku -e 'Date.new( .[2,1,0].join("-")).mm-dd-yyyy.put given $*IN.split("-")>>.chomp;'  <<< '19-07-2021'
07-19-2021
```

---

Because Raku handles `ISO 8601` dates by default, using the built-in `Date` object type can solve a lot of issues. So if you need to subtract dates, you can do so easily:

```bash
~$  raku -e 'my $d = Date.new: .[2,1,0].join("-") given $*IN.split("-")>>.chomp;   \
            my $today = Date.today;                    \
            say "Your date is $d.";                    \
            say "Todays date is $today.";              \
            say "The difference is {$today - $d} days.";'  <<< '19-07-2021'
Your date is 2021-07-19.
Todays date is 2023-09-20.
The difference is 793 days.
```

FYI, *"`Date.today` creates an object the current day according to the system clock."*

https://docs.raku.org/type/Date
https://docs.raku.org/language/temporal
https://docs.raku.org/routine/sprintf
https://raku.org