# Format date to another date format in bash

Tags: bash, rhel, date

I am retrieving the following dates from a database:

- 2022-04-12-08.22.28.940722
- 2018-10-30-10.28.10.112309
- 2022-04-07-14.13.19.426219

In my bash script I am writing them to a file (where the date is $lastlogintime):

```
echo -n " - Naam van gebruiker: $loginname - Laatste login: $lastlogintime" >> $LOGFILE
```

I want to save the date in another format, like this:

- 10-2-2023 14:48:27
- mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a date from DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD format in bash LINUX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659287/convert-a-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-bash-linux)

Comment: You might check whether the database itself provides date formatting functionality as required.

Comment: If you are fetching the dates from a field of some date or datetime format in a database, then it's very likely that the database also has date formatting capabilities built in that you can use in your `SELECT` statement.  Unfortunately, you don't mention what database backend you use nor what the database schema looks like.

Comment: I am using IBM DB2 database.